# 3 or 4 level dependent Drupal form

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to set up 3 or 4 level dependent. The options change as expected, but I want to hide the third and fourth options (the OK button in this case) when the first dropdown selection is changed.

I have also used #states but it doesn't have any effect.

How do I achieve that?

```
<?php

function myform_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['dropdown_form']['selection_one'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Selection One'),
    '#options' => _load_selection_one(),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'event' => 'change',
      'callback' =>'dropdown_form_selection_two',
      'wrapper' => 'selection_two-wrapper',
      'effect' => 'slide',
    ),
  );

  $form['dropdown_form']['wrapper'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="selection_two-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $options = array('- Select selection_two -');
  if(isset($form_state['values']['selection_one'])) {
    $options = _load_selection_two($form_state['values']['selection_one']);
  }

  $form['dropdown_form']['wrapper']['selection_two'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'event' => 'change',
      'callback' =>'dropdown_form_selection_three',
      'wrapper' => 'selection_three-wrapper',
      'effect' => 'slide',
    ),
  );

  $form['dropdown_form']['wrapper']['wrapper-selection_three'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="selection_three-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $selection_three_options = array();
  if(isset($form_state['values']['selection_two']) && $form_state['values']['selection_two'] != 0) {
    $selection_three = _load_selection_three($form_state['values']['selection_two']);
    foreach($selection_three as $key => $info) {
      $selection_three_options[$key] = $info['value'];
    }
  }

  $form['dropdown_form']['wrapper']['wrapper-selection_three']['selection_three'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $selection_three_options,
    '#states' => array(
      'invisible' => array(
        ':input[name=selection_two]' => array('value' => '0'),
      ),
    )
  );

  $form['dropdown_form']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('OK'),
    '#validate' => array('dropdown_form_validate'),
    '#submit' => array('dropdown_form_submit'),
  );

  if(empty($form_state['values']['selection_one'])) {
    $form['dropdown_form']['wrapper']['selection_two']['#attributes'] = array('style' => 'display:none');
  }

  return $form;
}

function dropdown_form_selection_two($form, $form_state) {
  // Return the dropdown list including the wrapper
  return $form['dropdown_form']['wrapper'];
}

function dropdown_form_selection_three($form, $form_state) {
  // Return the dropdown list including the wrapper
  return $form['dropdown_form']['wrapper']['wrapper-selection_three'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what, precisely, you're trying to achieve? I've used #states and it simply works...

Comment: @Ollie, I'm trying to hide options 3 and 4 when option 1 is changed. This is the test case:
Select option 1 (option 2 appears); select option 2 (option 3 appears); change option 1 (option 2 resets; option 3 should be hidden). Thanks!